# Explanation on UTF-8 magic in jsp

Tags: utf-8

I have just started working with internationalization and i have configured my system as follows :

1 .I have specified my database character encoding to be in UTF-8

2 .Added 2 line in my.cnf

```
 default-character-set=utf8
 default-collation=utf8_general_ci
```

3. At each jsp page added

`<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java"%>`

4.In my server.xml added URIEncoding="UTF-8"

Now my question is whenever i enter a "Number" which has variables in "int" in Bengali font its stored in English in the database . But if i enter any "String" in Bengali font its stored in the database as Bengali.
What is happening to the int type variables ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not being stored "in English" in the database; it's stored as an integer using the database's own representation of integers (probably binary or binary-coded decimal depending on the database). For most cases, this is almost certainly what you want.

Converting from a `String` (representing a number) to an `int` is called 'parsing'. Some code somewhere is probably calling `parse()` on a `NumberFormat` object, and this format object knows about the user's locale (which presumably allows for however numbers are written in Bengali).

The opposite (displaying an `int` as a `String`) is called 'formatting', and this can also know about the user's locale.

Comment: May be i could not clearly express my query .
Well let me give an example :
I have two fields named Age(int) and Name(String) , 
I have given Bengali text for both of the fields suppose age = ২৪
and Name =বাংলা. 
Then i store them in the database . 
When i retrieve the values from the database , from my gui 
I got that The Name is in Bengali(বাংলা) characters but the age is in English character(24) .

Comment: Oh, I see. Well this probably depends on how the integer is getting from the database to your UI element. You might need to edit your question to show your JSP code. But I don't think this is a UTF-8 encoding issue, I think it's a locale issue.